# Validate OpenAPI response with dredd

Tags: openapi, dredd

I have an OpenAPI v3 specification file with the following (showing just fragments):

```
paths:
  /global/name:
    get:
    description: Some description
    tags:
      - Global settings
    operationId: getGlobalSettingsName
    responses:
      # Response code
      '200':
        description: Successful response
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/globalSettingsName'

components:
  schemas:
    globalSettingsName:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: integer
          description: 'ID'
          example: 1
      required:
        - name
```

but the server response is:

```
{
  "name": "somestring"
}
```

Note the name property type is `integer` and in the server response, it is a `string` (on purpose) but `dredd` request passes (success).

Doesn't `dredd` check for response property types?

I redefined the response as `string` (not JSON):

```
responses:
    # Response code
    '200':
      description: Successful response
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: string
```

and `dredd` doesn't complain about either.

I even changed the property of the schema:

```
    globalSettingsName:
      type: object
      properties:
        www:
          type: string
          description: 'some description'
          example: 'somestring'
      required:
        - www
```

And same (success) result when it is expected to fail.

Aren't these validation supported by `dredd`? Am I using specification wrong?

Comment: This might be unrelated - but `example: 1` should be inside the `name` property definition instead of on the object level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It results that the current version (8.0.5) only supports example value in content: https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/issues/1281

Comment: Current level of OpenAPI v3 integration into Dredd is tracked as https://github.com/apiaryio/api-elements.js/issues/71 and until it's closed, it's still highly experimental.